# How to display jQuery json data in html div in php

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

[json data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b9hc8.png)

[Here see my result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xkOHl.png)

I am creating an admin panel dashboard in PHP, I want to display dynamic data in my dashboard and data must be display based on dropdown list, I got data in ajax success but how to that data display in html

```
<div class="col-lg-3">
    <form method="POST" class="appointment-form" id="appointment-form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <select onchange='fetch_val(this.value)' name="meeting" id="meeting">
            <option>--Select Meeting--</option>
                <?php
                $sql="SELECT * FROM meeting";
                $res=$conn->query($sql);
                while ($re=$res->fetch_object()) 
                {
                    ?>  
                    <option value="<?php echo $re->meeting_no; ?>"><?php echo $re->meeting_no; ?></option>
                    <?php
                }
                ?>
        </select>
    </form>
    <div class="bage">
        <h6 class="name">Register User</h6>
        <div class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-around">
            <p class="m-0 name-valu">HERE I WANT TO DISPLAY THAT DATA</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

HERE MY SCRIPT:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function fetch_val(val){                
    $.ajax({
        url:"load.php",
        type:"POST",
        data:{"meeting":val},
        dataType:"JSON",
        success:function(data){
            $('#reference_given').val((data[0].reference_given));
            $('#reference_taken').val((data[0].reference_taken));
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

Comment: what is the `#reference_given`? where are you trying to put the data?

Comment: i am just check that is wroking or not, i am  trying to get data using id

Comment: could you please show us how are you creating the response data of the ajax?

Comment: i had put image response,
look at top you will find image at left corner

Comment: no I want to see how you are generating these data from the serverside, it's better to be a valid JSON to be easier to access from the clientside.

Comment: Your response in the Network tab does not look like valid JSON. Probably better to use a json encoding function on the server side to serialize the payload. `json_encode` ships out the box.

Answer (score 0):

use ajax response to display it using $.each() and pass a div with id or class. in success function use this

```
    $.each(data, function(i, item) {

     $text+= '<div>'+ data[i].reference_given +'</div><br>'; 

    });​  
             
    if(text != ""){

           $("#display").append(text);   

     }
```

Hope this help